# Ionic4: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4

I'm working on an ionic4 app with angular and firebase.

I was building the app to android using: ionic cordova run android, it was successfully built the application.
Suddenly when I'm running the same command there is an error showing:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>           is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>           Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-37:19 to override.

I've tried to add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to  element at AndroidManifest.xml.
And I've have tried also to delete the platforms/android and install it again without getting the result

Does anyone have any idea about what happening? or can anyone help me with this issue!

Comment: which android version are you usin

Comment: android 9 API 28

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar issue I think, and found out it was because of AndroidX plugins. Here is what worked for me :

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Simply adding these plugins removed any build error.

Also, if you're still using the original firebase plugin you should replace it with one of the fixed forks : https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib or https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase

And `cordova clean android` then rebuild.

Note that you also need Android SDK 28 for it to work, and I recommend updating Cordova and ionic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove and re-add the android platform

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Comment: I tried the above commands and this error appears:  "Unable to find command".
I used "ionic cordova platform rm android" and "ionic cordova platform add android" and they succeeded in installing the Android platform. I run the build command and it gives me the same error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Correct, the latest version expect the cordova keyword as well